# React component's state has different values in render from values in setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a strange issue happening in between a component's button click and the render for that component. In the handler of the button click, I set the state of the component.  For one of the state values, I push an empty object onto the array and increment the other state value. On render, the state value which I added the empty object to becomes an integer.

I've added in the functions `componentWillUpdate` and `componentDidUpdate` to see if the state has already changed before reaching those functions, and it does.

```
class ItemGrouping extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: this.props.items,
            count: this.props.count,
            groupingName: this.props.groupingName
        };
        this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
    }

    addItem(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState((previousState, previousProps) => {
            return {
                count: previousState.count + 1,
                items: previousState.items.push({}),
                groupingName: previousState.groupingName
            };
        });
    }

    render() {
        let count = this.state.count;
        let items = this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
             let currentIndex = count;
             count += 1;
             return (
                 <EditableItem key={count} item={item} count={currentIndex} />
             );
        });

        return (
            <section className="card">
                {this.state.groupingName != '' &&
                    <h3 className="card-header">{this.state.groupingName}</h3>
                }
                <div className="card-body">
                     <div className="row item-grouping" data-grouping={this.state.groupingName}>
                        <div className="col-12">
                            {items}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="card-footer">
                    <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.addItem} type="button"><i className="dripicons-plus"></i> Add an Item</button>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        );
    }
}
```

Initial Render:

```
 state.count: 1,
 state.items: [{id: '', value: ''}]
```

Expected result after addItem:

```
state.count: 2,
state.items: [{id: '', value: ''}, {}]
```

Actual result after addItem:

```
state.count: 2,
state.items: 3
```

Could a child component be causing the state to change?  There isn't a parent component on the page that would trigger a state change for this component so I am a little lost.

Comment: on a side note .. [props in initial state is anti-pattern](https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be this: `items: previousState.items.push({})`, the `push` method returns the array's length not the resulting array.

Instead of `push` you can use something like this: `items: [...previousState.items, {}]`, or `items: previousState.items.concat({})`

Comment: Thank you so much for this Titus.  Seems I need to brush up on the MDN docs a bit.